# C# winforms Drag custom control to another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-component

I'm making a desktop replacement and I'm trying to add the ability to drag custom components from the desktop to another form in the same application but I can't get the `DoDragDrop` event to fire whilst dragging the components.

The component I want to drag is a child of the desktop. It is a Panel with a child PictureBox and Label. The desktop is simply a form. I have tried to use `DoDragDrop` when `OnMouseLeave` fires from the desktop but it doesn't seem to fire whilst I'm dragging the component. For the second form, I have tried I have events for `OnDragOver`, `OnDragEnter`, `OnDragDrop` and `OnMouseEnter` but, again, they don't fire whilst dragging the component.

I have this inside the desktop form:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    DoDragDrop("Test Data", DragDropEffects.All);

    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
}
```

And this is inside the second form:

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Instance.WriteLine("OnMouseEnter!");

    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
}

protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Instance.WriteLine("OnDragOver!");
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

    Console.WriteLine("Drag Over: " + e.Effect);

    base.OnDragOver(e);
}

private void Header_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Instance.WriteLine("Header Drag Enter!");
    Console.WriteLine("Header Drag Enter!");
}

protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string))) return;
    string data = (string)e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
    Console.WriteLine("Drag Drop: " + data);

    base.OnDragEnter(e);
}
```

Header is a panel used to drag second form because it's borderless. It's at the top of the form so thought that might catch it.

I'm guessing it has to do with the `OnMouseMove` event from the component blocking the `OnMouseLeave` event from the desktop form, but I can't figure out a way to determine if the mouse has left the desktop form whilst dragging the component.

Comment: "...I can't figure out a way to determine if the mouse has left the desktop form whilst dragging the component..."  doesn't the OnMouseLeave event fire?

Comment: @Eminem It fires when I'm not dragging the component, but if I'm dragging the component and move my mouse over the second form it doesn't fire.

Comment: MouseLeave does not fire because of the Capture property.  It is automatically set to *true* by OnMouseDown.  That ensures that the MouseUp, MouseClick and Click events can be reliably fired.  Hard to give specific advice, a "desktop replacement" is a rather ambitious undertaking and DoDragDrop() is not exactly a very suitable method.  The generic way to detect a drag is to record the mouse position with MouseDown and use MouseMove to detect motion while the left button is down.  Call DoDragDrop when it moved enough.